# How can I change this code into PHP prepared statements

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

This is a code that I made a pagination to display my gallery from the database. Now I need to convert this code into Prepared Statements, I am new to a prepared statement. I am really confused how to use prepared statements in this. As I mentioned I am new to prepared statements but now that I have come to do the queries using prepared statements, via the $stmt->fetch() statement, I don't know how to paginate now.

```
<?php
    $limit = 2;
    if(isset($_GET["page"])) {
        $page = $_GET["page"];
    } else {
        $page = 1;
    }
    ;
    $start_from = ($page - 1) * $limit;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM album_catagories ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start_from, $limit";
    $rs_result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
?> 
<div class="full-gallery">
    <h3>Gallery</h3>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="content">
            <?php
                while($image = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs_result)) {
                    echo '
                    <div class="album_holder">
                        <img id="myImg" src ="includes/uploads/images/gallery/' . $image['coverimage'] . '" class="gallery-image">
                        <p>' . $image['title'] . '</p>
                        <a id="purple-button" href="viewalbum.php?album=' . $image['id'] . '">View Album</a>
                    </div>';
                }
            ?> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pag-menu">
        <?php
            $sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM album_catagories";
            $rs_result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
            $row = mysqli_fetch_row($rs_result);

            $total_records = $row[0];
            $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $limit);
            $pagLink = "<nav><ul class='pagination'>";

            for($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++) {
                $pagLink .= "<li><a href='gallery.php?page=" . $i . "'>" . $i . "</a></li>";
            }
            ;
            echo $pagLink . "</ul></nav>";
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php include('footer.php'); ?>
```

Comment: @BenRoob why did you attach the PDO tag to this? It isn't PDO.

Comment: And who upvotes a `TL/DIFM` question

Comment: @RiggsFolly What is `TL/DIFM`?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Bet that comment wont stay for long :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly Gotcha, thanks for the explanation :)

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Sorry, probably my thoughts about "why not using PDO" misled me.

Comment: @BenRoob It's all good :) (I agree with "why not use PDO")

Comment: Can anyone help me in this....?

Comment: @SyedVikasBukhari Sure! The most help I can be is [linking you directly to the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) which you should read, attempt to convert your code, and post another question if you have any _specific problems_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will give you prepared statements and a response

```
<?php
    $limit = 2;
    if(isset($_GET["page"])) {
        $page = $_GET["page"];
    } else {
        $page = 1;
    }
    ;
    $start_from = ($page - 1) * $limit;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM album_catagories ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ?, ?";
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection,"SELECT * FROM album_catagories ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ?, ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,$start_from,$limit);
    $rs_result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
?>
```